# adding a uiTableView in landscape mode as a modalView

Tags: iphone

I am having a UITabBarController set up with many views, In one of the views , i have a UIbUTTON. On clicking this button or on a rotate , I wanted a landscape modal view controller having a tableViewController to popup.

Inside the modalviewController , on rotating to portait mode , it shud return back to the original orientation of the tabBarController.

I was UIDevice setOrientation for this, now this is being rejected by apple. Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In that modal view controller, implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation::` to only allow it to be displayed in a specific orientation.