# set interface orientation on iPhone private API

Tags: iphone, interface, screen-orientation

Can anyone confirm that `[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];` will get your app rejected by Apple.

Is there a good replacement available?

Answer (score 4):

[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation] is a private API, you can find that is signature is only in read-only (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation)).

If you want set the device orientation to Portrait or other mode you should override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: UIDevice is not a private API.

Comment: Yes sorry, it's a mistake, I'd just tell that the setOrientation is private.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes you'll get rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350382/adding-a-uitableview-in-landscape-mode-as-a-modalview).

You can change the frame and apply a transformation to the key window, and change the status bar orientation (which is public) to simulate changing the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UIInterfaceOrientation in your app plist

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It works perfectly on my apps

```
UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if (application.statusBarOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [app.viewController presentModalViewController:c animated:NO];
    [app.viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [c release];
}
```

where app.viewController is the rootViewController of the app